# How save javascript to a text file When get data from server with ajax in use of dataTable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I want use [DataTable bootstrap plugin](https://datatables.net/). I get data from server with ajax. i see this plugin for [ajax](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html). in this i see read data from a text file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

now my questio is, How can i save given data with ajax from server to a text file??
I use this code to give data from server with ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://79.../../getall",
                contentType:'application/json',
                data:'{ "requester": { "userName": "'+AdminUsername+'", "password": "'+AdminPass+'" } }',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (GetResult) {
                    if(GetResult.result){
                      result=GetResult.answer;
                    }

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            })
```

Comment: Why will you save as textfile? You cannot save without some user interaction, take a look at https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html and deriviations.

Comment: by saving the file, I am assuming you want to save on client's machine.
Use Blob service. Create a duplicate  button and tigger the download of the file in the success method the ajax. 
Use this Jsfiddle for reference http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/